# Combinatorics, probability and choosing committees

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A committee of 5 is to be chosen from a group of 8 men and 4 women.

Find the probability that

(a) the committee consists of 3 men, 2 women;

(b) the first person chosen for the committee is a man, given that the committee must include exactly 2 women;

(c) the first person chosen is a man, given that the last chosen is a woman.

My attempt at answers:

(a) $\displaystyle \frac{{8\choose3}\times{4\choose2}}{{12\choose5}}$

(b) ?

(c) $\displaystyle \frac{{8\choose1}\times{10\choose3}\times{4\choose1}}{{12\choose5}}\div \frac{{11\choose4}\times{4\choose1}}{{12\choose5}}$

Parts (b)/(c) I wasn't sure how to approach, but if someone could provide methods and correct answers for the different parts then I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't really understand b - surely the selection process is a factor - you could say that 2 are chosen at random, and then a process of choosing only from women or men is instigated as required - is just one of many ways of achieving the result - in that way the first choice is simply 8/12 for male

Comment: I was unsure myself. Very often these questions don't specify any particular order of selection.

Comment: @drhab - if you needed 10 women and one man from similar sized groups- then it's hard to see how bias in orders can't exist - for example if we stop choosing men after one is chosen, then 9 women followed by man is very unlikely, but one man followed 9 women seems likely.

Answer (score 1):

**Part (a):**
Ways of Selecting:
3 men out of 8: $\binom{8}{3}$, 2 women out of 4:$\binom{4}{2}$, 5 people from 12: $\binom{12}{5}$

$$P\text{(3 men & 2 women)} = \frac{\text{Favourable Outcomes}}{\text{All Outcomes}} = \frac{\binom{8}{3} \times \binom{4}{2}}{\binom{12}{5}} = \frac{336}{792}$$

**Part (b):**

$$P\text{(Man-first person & Exactly 2 women)} = \frac{\binom{8}{3} \times \binom{4}{2}}{\binom{12}{5}} \times \frac{3\times 4!}{5!} = \frac{336}{792} \times \frac{3}{5} = \frac{1008}{3960}$$

This requires multiplying the two probabilities. Note that the first fraction uses the result from **part (a)**.

Note I have some confusion (also discussed in the comments) regarding the wording of the question. The above calculations are assuming an AND condition - not that that the committee does include two women, now what is the probability of the first person being a man.

Comment: surely that's only true if they make all possible permutations, then select one of the qualifying permutations at random

Comment: I could be wrong. This is my interpretation of "having a man be the first person in the committee".

Comment: for c I wasn't sure if the 3 men and two women was in force, however if it isn't, then knowing that the last member is woman, then there are 8 men out of 11 people equally likely to be first - so 8/11 was what I got - but I deleted the working due to confusion over the committe breakdown limit in b

Comment: you could be right on all of them as well

Comment: Thanks. I am new to both maths and P&C. So the support always helps.

Comment: Should the top of the fraction not be the number of permutations with a woman last and man first?

Comment: Yes. That is what I wanted. That is why I have 3 * 3! * 2. The 3! gives the middle three people. The 2 at the end multiplies for the two choice that we have (for who will go at the end). And the 3 at the beginning multiplies for the three choices of who will go first.

Comment: I'm not sure that the question still requires 3 men and 2 women in the last bit, they are separate parts

Comment: You are right. Changed the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Does the alternative way for part (b) not give an answer greater than 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46595/discussion-between-wrb98-and-starlight).